# Remove newline character from each even string in txt python

Tags: python, string, text, newline

Strings read from a txt. The code removes page numbers in it. It works.

The question is that how to make removing of each newline symbol in even string. Also is it possible to remove newlines of each string what ends with number to unite digits and words as whole one?

---

**Example of testfile.txt**:

```
0000.0000.3214.6550
Chineese citizen
0000.0000.1264.2020
Dodge Challenger

     1
```

---

**Desired output.txt**:

```
0000.0000.3214.6550 Chineese citizen
0000.0000.1264.2020 Dodge Challenger
```

---

I even tried regex but it always removes everything after the first string. As in this way.

```
x = 1
with open("testfile.txt", "r") as input:
    with open("out.txt", "w") as output:
        for line in input:
            line = line.strip() #whitespace clearing
        try:
            int(line)           #checking
        except ValueError:
            output.write(line + "\n")
            x + x + 1
        for line in input:
            line = line.replace("\n", "")
```

Comment: Are you having trouble with your indentation?

Comment: As the result I just united two files and made the program based on reading consistently of two files and then via import os removed all garbage. the last output is always available after operations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a simple implementation:

```
# Read in all lines
with open('testfile.txt') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
# The lines end with a newline. Remove this for every other line.
lines = [line if i%2 else line.rstrip('\r\n') + ' '
    for i, line in enumerate(lines)]
# Combine modified lines
text = ''.join(lines)
# Write to file
with open('output.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.write(text)
```

The last character(s) (either `'\n'` or `'\r\n'`) is removed at even lines, where even lines are determined by `i%2` being falsy (actually `0`), where `i` is the line number. Also, in place of the newline we add a whitespace.

Comment: @Aran-Fey Ah yes, Windows... I've edited the answer.

Answer (score 2):

How about this (no fancy things):

```
with open("out.txt", "w") as output:
    odd_line = True
    with open("testfile.txt", "r") as input:
        for line in input:
            if odd_line:
                s = line.strip() # save to a variable
            else:
                output.write('{} {}'.format(s, line) # append to output after concatenating
            odd_line = not odd_line
```

Comment: Using `strip` is no good as it removes from both ends. Additionally, using `strip()` with no arguments also removes whitespace.

Answer (score 0):

This should help.

```
s = """0000.0000.3214.6550
Chineese citizen
0000.0000.1264.2020
Dodge Challenger"""

res = []
for i, v in enumerate(s.split("\n")):     #Using enumerate to find index
    v = v.strip()
    if not res:                           #Check if list is empty
        res.append(v)
    else:
        if i%2 != 0:                      #Check odd-even number of line
            res[-1] = res[-1] + " " + v
        else:
            res.append(v)
for i in res:
    print(i)
```

Output:

```
0000.0000.3214.6550 Chineese citizen
0000.0000.1264.2020 Dodge Challenger
```

Comment: This won't work for text that's read from a file. When you iterate over a file, the lines will have line breaks at the end. It's not obvious how to correctly rewrite your code to make it work with files.

Comment: @Aran-Fey You are right. Adding a `.strip()` should fix it. Thanks

Comment: Well, that'll remove other whitespace too, not just line breaks... but ok I guess.

Comment: @Rakesh I haven't mentioned but the list is going for many pages down. There are thousand strings like that. I appreciate the help

Answer (score 0):

The following should answer your first question using the text you shared:

> how to remove of each newline symbol in even string?

```
import io


text = """0000.0000.3214.6550
Chineese citizen
0000.0000.1264.2020
Dodge Challenger"""

with io.StringIO(text) as input, open("out.txt", "w") as output:
    for i, line in enumerate(input, 1):
        if i % 2 != 0:
            print(line.strip("\n"), end="\t", file=output)
        else:
            print(line, end="", file=output)
```

It `enumerates` the lines of the text and `strips` them if the line number is odd. That removes the newline characters and with the use of the `print`, you replace them with tabs. You could have chosen whatever other character you want for this replacement.

> Also is it possible to remove newlines of each string what ends with
>   number to unite digits and words as whole one?

```
with io.StringIO(text) as input, open("out.txt", "w") as output:
    for line in input:
        if line[-2].isdigit():
            print(line.strip("\n"), end="\t", file=output)
        else:
            print(line, end="", file=output)
```

This one is pretty similar to the previous one, with the only difference being that here you're checking if the character before the newline character of each line is a digit.

Please note that if you're using python2, the `print` function will need to be imported at the top of your script as follows:

`from __future__ import print_function`

I hope this proves useful.